# cannot add new column (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN')

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

When I run this

```
ALTER TABLE agency
ADD COLUMN single_word varchar(100)
```

I get

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN'.

I tried removing the `COLUMN` but still same problem.

Comment: owned and operated by ? - is there some other code here your not showing - also what flavor of sql (mysql, tsql, psql).

Comment: It's really Microsoft **SQL Server** - just *SQL* is nothing but the *structured query language* - a language spec, not a product....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For TSQL Flavor try this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE agents
ADD [associated department] varchar(100)
```

Comment: I just started and didn't know Microsoft's flavor is TSQL. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow enable standards mode or something on SQL Server or on the client so that standard SQL statements can be executed? Statement like the one OP has written?
Or do I have to write the upgrade scripts for my product in 2 flavors?

Answer (score 6):

I have same issue when running that query on HeidiSQL. The solution is simple, change the query to be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "agency"
ADD "single_word" varchar(100)
```

just remove "COLUMN" keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the database software you are using, if you want to have a space in the column name (which I would recommend against), you will have to escape it.

For example, in MySQL, you would use the backtick (the character to the left of the number 1 at the top of the keyboard) :

```
ALTER TABLE agents
ADD COLUMN `associated department` varchar(100);
```

For SQL Server, you can use `[]`, and for most other DBMSes, the double-quote (`"`) will escape identifiers

Comment: And some require ; at the end. So much for all the guessing game... please specify your database engine.